# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) -Ask Expert project using tkinter

Tags: python

I know that this question has been asked before, which is why I've checked the internet before posting this question. I tried all sorts of solutions, including `if len(line.split())<2: continue`, but none of it worked. So if any of you know some solution that I may have not tried yet please let me know. Thank You in advance.

Here is my python code. By the way I am using Python 3.6.0.

```
    from tkinter import Tk, simpledialog, messagebox

def read_from_file():

    with open('capital_data.txt') as file:
        for line in file:
            line=line.rstrip('\n')
            country, city = line.split('/')
            the_world[country]=city

def write_to_file(country_name, city_name):
    with open('capital_data.txt','a') as file:
        file.write('\n' + country_name + '/' + city_name)

print('Ask The Expert-Capital Cities Of The World')
root=Tk()
root.withdraw()
the_world={}


read_from_file()


while True:
    query_country = simpledialog.askstring('Country', 'Type the name of the country: ')


    if query_country in the_world:
        result = the_world[query_country]

        messagebox.showinfo('Answer',
                            'The capital city of ' + query_country + ' is ' + result + '!')
    else:
        new_city = simpledialog.askstring('Teach me',
                                          'I don\'t know!' +
                                          'What is the capital city of ' + query_country + '?')
        the_world[query_country] = new_city
        write_to_file(query_country, new_city)
```

Comment: Have your program `print(line)` right before the you `split` for every line.  The last line it prints will be the problem line, and you can work out why it's happening.

Comment: `country, city = line.split('/')` You have an input line that does not contain any slashes, therefore `split()` returns only one element, which is not enough to assign to `country, city`.

Comment: ok it printed the last line and now what

Comment: how do i fix that John Gordon

Comment: Oh its working now

Answer (score 0):

One of the lines in `capital_data.txt` does not contain a `/`. As a result, the line: `country, city = line.split('/')` is not able to provide you two values. Either your data is not correct as expected by your code, or you should adjust your code to deal with a varying number of elements generated by that line.

One approach could be something like `row_data = line.split('/')` and then you operate on that based on how many elements are returned.

Another approach is a try/except statement to handle erroneous rows:

```
try:
    country, city = line.split('/')
except ValueError:
    # code to handle the error
```